# Target advertising based on google search?

Tags: javascript, html, ads, adsense

I'm currently building a website that targets a specific niche.
Basically I want to advertise some local businesses and here's what I want:

Let's say when the user searches Google for a mechanic; I want to be able to track that keyword and display one or more the businesses I have listed on my website.
In other words: when the user arrives on my site, I want to display a list of mechanics based on the search.

Does Google Adsense do such thing? 
Is there any other platform that enables me to do that?
If not, How can I build that functionality myself?

Comment: One time I google searched where the nearest Mattress Firm was. Facebook, Google Adsense, and Amazon all decided to start showing me ads for mattresses. I don't feel like you need to build this functionality.

Comment: ------Bump-----